# Stack Exchange app won't let me comment on my question

Tags: bug, comments, android-app

I am trying out the SE Android app on my (really old) phone. I am on Android 4.4.2 (Kitkat). When I tried to comment on my own [question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17326/unpublished-questions-written-on-mobile-site-not-showing-on-desktop-site) (first attempt at commenting on the app) the app let me write my comment, but nothing happened when I tappped ***post***. The button even showed the click effects but did not post the comment.

I went out, went back in and tried again, with the same result.

Is the app not compatible with my Android, or is this a bug? So far my experience with the app has not been satisfactory.

**Update:** The app let me comment under my question [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/84067/how-many-atoms-can-be-reduced-in-a-single-redox-reaction), but would not let me comment on the answer (not mine) on the same thread.

Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: What version is the app?

Comment: Also, please post a link to the question, maybe there is account problem e.g. you posted it using a different account by mistake so you can't comment with less than 50 rep.

Comment: It is version 1.0.95, which is the latest which I am offered. I only have one account, and the desktop site lets me comment on my own questions. The question is the same as is linked in this question.

Comment: Still, link to the question can be useful to debug. (even for the dev team as we can't know what question you refer to.)